# jSON get request using local storage API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, local-storage

I was wondering if anyone could offer some assistance with this problem I am currently having. I'm completely new at this, and unfortunately the textbook Headfirst into programming doesn't really explain this very well. I researched many stackoverflows, but no avail. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

The tasks is to display a food menu along with a list of items below.

1. Should be generated with the data from a JSON file retrieved via an Ajax GETrequest.
2. Generate the JSON file containing the desired menu items.
3. You decide HOW to display the menu items. i.e. ordered list, unordered list etc.
4. Cache the data from the JSON response using the localStorge API
5. Ensure that GET requests are not made to after the data is cached.
6. Retrieve data from localStorage when data is cached

I think this is the correct get request? I know I'm missing stuff but honestly it's over my head.

```
function getStarterMenu() {
    $.get(
        'data/startersMenu.json',
        function (data) {
            //Something goes here?
        },
        'json'
        );
}
```

I have the external json file called startersMenu.json here

```
var startersMenu = {
"starters": [
{
"name": "Jumbo Lump Crab Cake",
"description": "Creole lobster sauce."
},

{
"name": "Bacon Wrapped Sea Scallops",
"description": "Chardonnay lemon sauce, Mango salsa."
},
{
"name": "Chilled Maine Lobster Cocktail",
"description": "Atomic cocktail sauce and lemon butter."
},
{
"name": "Coconut Shrimp",
"description": "three jumbo tiger shrimp, vanilla orange beurre blanc."
},
{
"name": "Crispy Point Judith Calamari",
"description": "Italian peppers and Bleu cheese Stuffed olives, Atomic cocktail sauce."
},
{
"name": "Oysters on the Half Shell",
"description": "shucked to order, mignonette and Atomic cocktail sauces."
}

]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<startersMenu.starters.length; i++){
localStorage.setItem('name_'+i, JSON.stringify(startersMenu.starters[i].name));

var nameString = localStorage.getItem("name_"+i);
console.log(nameString);
}
```

By this way you can store the data using local storage and retrieve easily..

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'data/startersMenu.json',
            data: {

            },
            cache: false,            // you can set cache true or false here

         complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
           // following statements 

        }
});
```

You have choosen method is better way. you can set cache true or false to store cache..

Using this way of approach is better way of helps to you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to store your json data after the success response from the ajax call. Note that you need to stringify the json you get before saving to local storage. 
`localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(json));`
You can then check your localstorage everytime before making ajax call again.
`localStorage['key']`
If there is data then take it from local storage otherwise call server for data.